# How to make decorator/descriptor managed attribute accept an iterable to eliminate code duplication?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators, python-descriptors

The code below is from this [repo](https://github.com/slideclick/py3book31/blob/master/Valid.py). It accompanies the book [Programming in Python 3: A Complete Introduction to the Python Language (Developer's Library)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001OFK2DK).

This part of the code shows using the `valid_number` decorator to enforce `minimum` and `maximum` values for the `price` and `quantity` of `StockItem`.

```
@valid_number('price', minimum=0, maximum=1e6)
@valid_number('quantity', minimum=1, maximum=1000)
class StockItem:

    def __init__(self, name, category, price, quantity):
        self.name = name
        self.category = category
        self.price = price
        self.quantity = quantity
```

In my case, I have a class with two attributes with the same constraints, so the decorators would look like:

```
@valid_number('price', minimum=0, maximum=1e6)
@valid_number('quantity', minimum=0, maximum=1e6)
class StockItem:
    ...
```

I'd like to be able to write something like...

```
@valid_number(['price','quantity'], minimum=0, maximum=1e6)
```

to apply the constraint to both attributes. I'm still working through all the nuances of decorators and descriptors, so I don't know if this is possible. The complete implementation of the descriptor and decorator are in the [repo](https://github.com/slideclick/py3book31/blob/master/Valid.py).

Comment: Yes, I would imagine that's possible. However I suspect that's *accidental* duplication; the min and max for price and quantity may *currently* be the same, but they likely have different reasons to change, so you probably shouldn't deduplicate it. And guiding you through how to do that is too broad for SO.

Comment: In my case , min and max aren't going to change. The valid options are strings in a tuple.